# How to prevent component from collecting unneccessary dependencies?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a component that is based on some nested state. E.g.

```
<rect width="some.deep.state.width">
```

Whenever any object in this path is altered (not newly set), the component re-renders even though nothing changed.

For example, the following leads to a rerender:

```js
Vue.set(some.deep, 'newProp', something)
```

One can imagine, that this is highly undesired especially when using nested state in a store and some array values change.

In my case I, save multiple entities in my store and whenever a new instance of that entity is added, all components based on that entity rerender even though nothing changed.

So is there a way to prevent collecting this (technical) deps (pun intended)?
Can I prevent Vue from collecting deps by some mechanism?

PS: I know, that this mechanism is useful in other places. In my case, it is not desired

Codesandbox which shows that behavior (in the console): https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-playground-forked-sx534?file=/components/hello.js

Inline Example - update is triggered:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return { some: { nested: { prop: 6 }}}
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log('component created')
    
    setTimeout(function () {
    
      Vue.set(this.some, 'otherProp', 10)
    
    }.bind(this), 2000)
  },
  updated: function () {
    console.log('component updated')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 Prop: {{ some.nested.prop }}
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your [mcve] **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) (the `[<>]` toolbar button), they support Vue.js.

Comment: The link is not required for understanding the question. It's only a proove. However, you are right anyway. Will add it

Comment: I don't expect the `rect` component to re-render unless `some.deep.state.width` changes.   Are you getting a different behaviour? If so, that's strange.

Comment: @Tony i will add a working example soon. Meanwhile you can take a look at the link. It's not strange behavior. Just how vue works

Comment: @Fuzzyma, what bothers you about the re-rendering? Is it a visual thing? or a performance thing? or both.

Comment: @Tony performance. This is not only one component rerendering but 100 on every mouse move in the end and that's not sustainable

Comment: In that case, can the data structure from the data store (a database, I assume) be simplified? That's the best solution I can think of now. Over-riding the default behaviour of a framework is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Tony no, it is already normalized. That's also not the question I am asking here. Thanks for your help, though. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it was by watching the deeply nested properties. Watchers seem to not register for changes I explained in my question. Therefore I added a watcher for every property which sets a property on the component which in turn I can use in the template.

This solved the problem of unnecessary re-renders, however, it turned out that multiple watchers whose values change simultaneously each trigger a rerender.
This is strange since all watchers execute in one dom cycle and therefore should only trigger one rerender. If anyone knows the reason for this, feel free to elaborate!

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      some: { nested: { prop: 6 }},
      theProp: null
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log('component created')
    
    this.$watch(() => this.some.nested.prop, (newValue) => this.theProp = newValue, {immediate: true})
    
    setTimeout(() => {
    
      // Does not triggers update
      Vue.set(this.some, 'otherProp', 10)
    
    }, 2000)
    
    setTimeout(() => {
    
      // Triggers update
      this.some.nested.prop = 10
    
    }, 4000)
  },
  updated: function () {
    console.log('component updated')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 Prop: {{ theProp }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem isn't prevent component from collecting unneccessary dependencies. Vue renderWatcher collected `some.deep` dependencies already when you using `<rect width="some.deep.state.width">` in template. Then executing `Vue.set(this.some.deep, 'newProp', something)` will notify all collected `some.deep` watcher which includes renderWatcher which will trigger rerender.

I have a hack solution which are stop renderWatcher running if you ensure that you wan't to rerender.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return { some: { deep: { prop: 6 }}}
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log('component created')
    
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('trigger rerender?')
      Vue.set(this.some, 'otherProp', 10)
      this.preventRerender()
    }.bind(this), 2000)
  },
  render(h) {
    console.log('render')
    return h('div', this.some.deep.prop)
  },
  methods: {
    // keep calling at the code end
    preventRerender() {
      this._watcher.active = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this._watcher.active = true
      })
    }
  }
})
```

You must notice that the updated hook is still triggered.

Comment: How it comes that the update hooks are still triggered even though you prevent the watcher from executing?

Comment: @Fuzzyma Because of triggering update hook aren't the renderWatcher's job.This is the job for flushSchedulerQueue which are run a queue of watchs which contains renderWatch and then trigger updated hook.

Comment: @Fuzzyma If you wan't updated hook was triggered.Thinking about override `ob` object like this: `const temp = this.some.__ob__.dep.notify;this.some.__ob__.dep.notify = () => {};this.$nextTick(() => this.some.__ob__.dep.notify = temp)`

Comment: Wow that's a big hack. Interesting though :).

Comment: Yes. `Vue.set` let `this.some` notified renderWatcher running.But you wan't renderWatcher to be executing.

Comment: So we can let renderWatcher not running or let `this.some` not notify renderWatcher.